# Подключение бота к телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot

У меня есть вопрос. Возможно это оффтоп, помогите советом. Есть эхо бот на питоне. Он работает пока консоль открыта. Как мне его сделать онлайн, чтобы даже после закрытия консоли он продолжал работать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно python ботов ставят на Heroku (550 бесплатных часов в месяц). Нужно создать в папке с ботом файл с requirements.txt, где должны указать все модули python, которые скачивали для работы бота. Легче всего такой список получить, прописав в командной строке команду `pip freeze`.
Чтобы залить бота на heroku, нужно либо скачать Heroku CLI и загрузить прямо с компьютера, либо залить на github, а потом просто вставить ссылку на github.
Запускается бот с хоста по нажатию одной кнопки.
Чтобы открыть логи бота, нужно установить Heroku CLI и в cmd прописать `heroku logs --tail --app <название проекта на heroku>`.
Подробнее можете прочитать в интернете или на самом сайте.

Comment: Спасибо, а как указать порт, бота выбивает через 60 секунд.

Comment: Порт? Вы вебхуки что ли используете?

Comment: Нет, но бота всеравно выбивает.

Comment: А токен бота где хранится?

Comment: в самом коде бота

Comment: Надо код тогда смотреть